# Return number of rows in select command - stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am Executing One query using stored procedure object. i want to retreive number of rows returns in Select Statement after executing the query.

I am Confused between using `ExecuteReader() & ExecuteScalar()`

```
public static int getDuplicateEvent(string ATM, string Fault1, string Fault2, ref SqlConnection Connection)
{
    string sQuery = "";
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        sQuery = /*Query With Format Select Code From A Union Select Code From B */
        using (SqlStoredProcedure sspObj = new SqlStoredProcedure(sQuery, Connection, CommandType.Text))
        {
            result = (int)sspObj.ExecuteScalar();
            sspObj.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception xObj)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `sspObj.Dispose();` is redundant since you're using `using` anyway.

Comment: You *only* want to know the number of records or *also* want to know the number of records? If it's only use Scalar in combination with Select Count(*) etc. Or if its also retrieve the data and count your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns the first column of the first row of the results

`ExecuteReader` returns a datareader that can be iterated through

You could also use `ExecuteNonQuery` or `Fill` into a `DataSet` or `DataTable`

Assuming you want the rows and the count, I would [fill a DataTable](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/406/filling-a-datatable-or-dataset-the-quick-way) and count the rows using `Rows.Count`

Comment: How to return Rows affected by Select Clause then ? i Want just Number

Comment: But i don't see that OP uses a `SqlCommand` but a `SqlStoredProcedure` (whatever it is).

Answer (score 1):

Create a query something in the lines of:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users`

Then use the `ExecuteScalar` to receive the number of rows.

[ExecuteScaler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

[ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx) Sends the CommandText to the Connection and builds a SqlDataReader.